# Handle Slack button action POST request data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, slack

I'm trying to make confirmation slack button while running slash command. e.g. I run slash-command (`/test`) it sends the POST request to my python app which sends back 2 buttons (Confirm, Cancel). User presses one of the buttons slack triggers an action and sends another POST request to my app. All is working fine before this step - I cannot handle the data from 2nd POST request correctly.

In the Slack documentation I found this:

> When an action is invoked, a request will be sent to the app's Request URL as configured above; the request body will contain a payload parameter that your app should parse for JSON.

When I do

```
data=json.loads(request.form["payload"])
return jsonify(data)
```

I get

```
{
 "action_ts": "XXXX",
 "actions": [
   {
     "name": "confirm",
     "type": "button",
     "value": "confirm"
   }
 ],
 "attachment_id": "X",
 "callback_id": "XXXX",
 "channel": {
   "id": "XXXX",
   "name": "XXXX"
 },
 "is_app_unfurl": false,
 "message_ts": "XXXX",
 "response_url": "XXXX",
 "team": {
   "domain": "XXXX",
   "id": "XXXX"
 },
 "token": "XXXX",
 "trigger_id": "XXXX",
 "type": "interactive_message",
 "user": {
   "id": "XXXX",
   "name": "XXXX"
 }
}
```

After when I call

```
data=json.loads(request.form["payload"]) 
action=data["actions"]
return jsonify(action)
```

I get

```
[
    {
        "name": "confirm",
        "type": "button",
        "value": "confirm"
    }
]
```

Now when I'm trying to get value of `"name"` with `action["name"]` I receive the error

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I tried `json.dumps(action)` and `json.dumps(action["name"])` neither of them worked.
How to read that values? I need to check value of `name` and then do the rest with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[
{
"name": "confirm",
"type": "button",
"value": "confirm"
}
]
```

is a list containing one element - the dictionary. Access the name like `data["actions"][0]["name"]`

Comment: You're welcome. If it solved the problem, please accept the answer.